# Unable to upgrade MVC framework to .net6.0

Tags: c#, .net, upgrade, .net-6.0

While upgrading mvc project to .net6.0 getting below error:

> Problem loading file in MSBuild workspace Msbuild failed when processing the file 'D:\CDT\CommonLibraries\ReferenceDataAPIClient\ReferenceDataAPIClient.csproj' with message: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets: (30, 5): The "ResolvePackageFileConflicts" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\tools\net6.0\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\tools\net6.0\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.Tasks.dll'. The system cannot find the path specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

It is trying to find net6.0 inside tools folder which does not exist. Can someone help here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, not sure why this folder is not here anymore, however, what I would suggest:

Go to the `net472` folder in the tools folder, here you can find this dll, you can copy all of the contents of this folder and then, create another folder in tools called `net6.0` and paste the copied files here, hopefully this works.

Comment: On my computer, the requested versions are located in the SDK folder and not in the Visual Studio folder:

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.404\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\tools\net6.0\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.Tasks.dll
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\tools\net472\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.Tasks.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\tools\net472\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.Tasks.dll.config`